# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Review, Failure/Error: @review = Review.new

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error in my tests in this Ruby project I am doing.  I can't seem to figure out why.
Below is my controller.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

def new
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
@review = Review.new
end

def create
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
@restaurant.reviews.create(review_params)
end
private
 def review_params
 params.require(:review).permit(:thoughts, :rating)
 end

end
```

Below is my view for the Reviews.

```
<%= form_for [@restaurant, @review] do |f| %>
<%= f.label :thoughts %>
<%= f.text_area :thoughts %>
<%= f.label :rating %>
<%= f.select :rating, (1..5) %>
<%= f.submit 'Leave Review' %>
 <% end %>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The model for the Review is wrong.  My model was referring to the wrong class.

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

When it should have been the following.

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :restaurant
end
```